# How to eliminate square roots in polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

From the determinant of a matrix $\mathbf M$, I  derive a symbolic expression of a polynomial say for example, `1 + a*x^2 + b*x^4 + Sqrt[a^2 - (x + c)^2] - Sqrt[a^2 - (x - c)^2] == 0` . (My actual equation is far more complex than that) The obvious way to eliminate square roots manually is to shift to right hand side the sqrt term and square both side, rearrange and repeat until the all square root terms vanish.  This way we preserve equation without any limit approach.  Does *Mathematica* have a function for this?

Comment: Why do you want to eliminate the square root?  Why not just solve your equation?  Also `Sqrt[x^-c]` is non-syntactic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Eliminate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate) for this. Include auxiliary variables `s1` and `s2`, and then eliminate them:

```
Eliminate[
    {1 + a x^2 + b x^4 + s1 - s2 == 0, s1^2 == x^2 + c, s2^2 == x^2 - c},
    {s1, s2}
]
```

> -1 + 4 x^2 - 4 a x^2 + 8 a x^4 - 6 a^2 x^4 - 4 b x^4 + 4 a^2 x^6 - 
>     4 a^3 x^6 + 8 b x^6 - 12 a b x^6 - a^4 x^8 + 8 a b x^8 - 
>     12 a^2 b x^8 - 6 b^2 x^8 - 4 a^3 b x^10 + 4 b^2 x^10 - 
>     12 a b^2 x^10 - 6 a^2 b^2 x^12 - 4 b^3 x^12 - 4 a b^3 x^14 - 
>     b^4 x^16 == 4 c^2

An alternative usually suggested by @DanielLichtblau is the use of [`GroebnerBasis`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroebnerBasis):

```
GroebnerBasis[
    {1 + a x^2 + b x^4 + s1 - s2, s1^2 - x^2 - c, s2^2 - x^2 + c},
    x,
    {s1, s2}
]
```

> {1 + 4 c^2 - 4 x^2 + 4 a x^2 - 8 a x^4 + 6 a^2 x^4 + 4 b x^4 - 
>     4 a^2 x^6 + 4 a^3 x^6 - 8 b x^6 + 12 a b x^6 + a^4 x^8 - 
>     8 a b x^8 + 12 a^2 b x^8 + 6 b^2 x^8 + 4 a^3 b x^10 - 4 b^2 x^10 + 
>     12 a b^2 x^10 + 6 a^2 b^2 x^12 + 4 b^3 x^12 + 4 a b^3 x^14 + 
>     b^4 x^16}

Comment: I just corrected my question. Typo mistake.  But I think I know how to modify your solution.  My apologies.

Comment: in case if `Eliminate` works, is there a way to remove '==' sign from results, so that its results can be used further for calculations?

Comment: I wish I understood what `GroebnerBasis` is.  It seems like a powerful function, but I don't know how to use it to solve problems...

Comment: `GroebnerBasis[]` can actually handle the expressions with square roots, but you need to pick out the desired expression from the results: `Select[GroebnerBasis[1 + a*x^2 + b*x^4 + Sqrt[a^2 - (x + c)^2] - Sqrt[a^2 - (x - c)^2], x], FreeQ[#, Power[_, _Rational]] &]`. @Quantum, it's basically a generalization of Gaussian elimination. See [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3550), or read *[Cox/Little/O'Shea](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-35651-8)* for an intro.